# How to customize rows by name with pgfplotstable?

Tags: tables, pgfplotstable

I have a table

```
Rank ITML  SDALF KISSME LDM   LMNN 
1    5.53  5.60  14.17  13.51 7.29 
5    18.89 23.45 48.54  40.73 21.00
10   29.96 36.09 52.57  52.13 32.06
20   44.20 51.96 70.53  70.81 48.94
```

The result I want is like

[image]

Concretely, I need to

- Change row name to add citation
- Make a row in **bold** style
- Add `\midrule` behind a row in a specific name

In `pgfplotstable`, columns can be easily refered using their names. But I cannot find a solution to customize the row style as easy as column. Few solutions I can use `pgfplotstabletranspose` to make the table row-wise, but the first column is not treated as name, but a column of data in string type, which result in the following picture:

[image]

And in this way the row can only be refered to in number. I may change one row name like this:

```
\pgfplotstabletranspose[string type, colnames from=Rank, input colnames to=Rank]\loadedtable{cuhk03-sota.txt}
\pgfplotstabletypeset[
   string type,
   every head row/.style={before row=\toprule, after row=\midrule},
   every last row/.style={after row=\hline},
   every row 0 column Rank/.style={/pgfplots/table/@cell content/.add={\relax}{\cite{davis2007information}},},
}{\loadedtable}
```

But this is obviously not a neat way. When I add a row in the middle, all the row numbers below have to be changed! Is there a good way to deal with row names?

Comment: Adding the citation is the tricky bit.  You might be better off using a tabular and \pgfplotstablegetelem.

Comment: @JohnKormylo `"Adding the citation is the tricky bit."` I don't know why :)

Answer (score 1):

*I don't agree with @JohnKormylo* ;) The problem is not the citation, the problem is to

**· Hack the `head row` for adding the word 'Rank' in some columns:**

```
every head row/.style={
typeset cell/.code={%% add the word 'Rank'...
\ifnum\pgfplotstablecol=\pgfplotstablecols%
\pgfkeyssetvalue{/pgfplots/table/@cell content}{Rank ##1\\}%
\else%
\ifnum\pgfplotstablecol=1%
\pgfkeyssetvalue{/pgfplots/table/@cell content}{##1 &}%
\else%
\pgfkeyssetvalue{/pgfplots/table/@cell content}{Rank ##1 &}%
\fi\fi%
}%%
},
```

**· The citation, on the other hand, can simply be added by using `biblatex/biber`,**
where we have to use a matching bibliography,  and then

```
display columns/0/.style={
postproc cell content/.style={@cell content={##1 \cite{##1} }}
},
```

(or maybe another 'citation source' too; depending on where the labels come from).

**· Alltogether:**

[image]

```
% arara: pdflatex
% arara: biber
% arara: pdflatex
% arara: pdflatex

\RequirePackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@book{ITML,
title     = {Citation of ITML},  
}
@book{SDALF,
title     = {Citation of SDALF},  
}
@book{KISSME,
title     = {Citation of KISSME},  
}
@book{LDM,
title     = {Citation of LDM},  
}
@book{LMNN,
title     = {Citation of LMNN},  
}
\end{filecontents}

\documentclass[border=5pt, varwidth]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplotstable}

\usepackage[style=numeric]{biblatex} 
\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}
\usepackage[colorlinks=true, citecolor=purple, pdfborder={0 0 0}]{hyperref}

\begin{document}
\pgfplotstableread[header=true]{
Rank ITML  SDALF KISSME LDM   LMNN 
1    5.53  5.60  14.17  13.51 7.29 
5    18.89 23.45 48.54  40.73 21.00
10   29.96 36.09 52.57  52.13 32.06
20   44.20 51.96 70.53  70.81 48.94
}\Actual

\textbf{\Large  Actual:} \pgfplotstabletypeset[string type]{\Actual} 
\bigskip

\pgfplotstableset{string type,
column type={>{\bfseries}c}, % bfseries for head row (1/2)
postproc cell content/.append style={% normalfont for cells (2/2)
/pgfplots/table/@cell content/.add={\fontseries{\seriesdefault}\selectfont}{}
},
%
every head row/.style={
before row=\hline, 
after row=\hline,
typeset cell/.code={%% add the word 'Rank'...
\ifnum\pgfplotstablecol=\pgfplotstablecols%
\pgfkeyssetvalue{/pgfplots/table/@cell content}{Rank ##1\\}%
\else%
\ifnum\pgfplotstablecol=1%
\pgfkeyssetvalue{/pgfplots/table/@cell content}{##1 &}%
\else%
\pgfkeyssetvalue{/pgfplots/table/@cell content}{Rank ##1 &}%
\fi\fi%
}%%
},
%
every last row/.style={
after row=\hline,
},
%
display columns/0/.style={% citations
postproc cell content/.style={@cell content={##1 \cite{##1} }},
column type=l,
},
}

\textbf{\Large Target:} \pgfplotstabletranspose[
colnames from=Rank,
input colnames to=Method,
]\Target{\Actual}
\pgfplotstabletypeset[]{\Target}

%\cite{ITML} 
\printbibliography[title=Citations]
\end{document}
```